# Syncing data to/from multiple devices to a cloud?

Tags: java, android, cloud

Interested in existing api packages, examples, guides, best practices etc on syncing data from multiple android devices to a server.  This would be  data that is stored in my application and could be sent to/from the server using any means necessary, probably JSON.

The server doesn't have to be java but that would be preferred.